# Earth Engine JRC database : Filtering date from image

Tags: google-earth-engine

I used JRC image collection which is an image of global surface water from 1984-2015.

> var gsw = ee.Image('JRC/GSW1_0/GlobalSurfaceWater');

Is there anyone who previously worked with that database?

The problem is I cannot filter date from the image.
Is it possible to filterDate from the image. Or filterDaate is only applicable for imageCollection.

I am new in earth engine, pls help me out.

Answer (score 1):

Here you can find the description of the data set as well as every other data sets 
[Data set description from GEE](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/datasets/catalog/JRC_GSW1_0_GlobalSurfaceWater)

> This mapping layers product **consists of 1 image** containing 7 bands. It maps different facets of the spatial and temporal distribution of surface water over the last 32 years. Areas where water has never been detected are masked.

You can inspect the bands and other related Infos by adding

```
print(gsw);
```

Another nice and fast option to find related information is to use the search toolbar inside the code editor. When you search for Surface Water you will find related data sets and by clicking on it you get all in formations (bands, properties...)